# My website Google page rank is always showing zero even after doing SEO

Tags: seo

Please guide me to get my site in Google ranking as after doing some SEO still Google page rank is zero.

Comment: This is too broad, and you can contact google on this..

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth SEO questions are not off-topic I guess

Comment: @Mr.Alien: Only if they can be translated into a coding problem ;)

Answer (score 2):

SEO is a wide field and PageRank one of possibly thousands of signals in Googles ranking algorithms: PageRank works by counting the number and quality of links to a page to determine a rough estimate of how important the website is... [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PageRank)

Comment: Upvoted cuz it was your first answer, but would like you to read the FAQ of the website :) happy Stackoverflow..

Answer (score 0):

Also what sort of time scale are you talking about? As in if you did all this in the last week it can take a long time for googles bots to re-index your site. Proper SEO can take months before reaping the benefits.